# Delete some text in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to delete some text where started with 09 in laravel?

for example this is my input ** سلام این شماره تلفن من است: ۰۹۸۷۶۵۴۳۲۱۷ **

i need to save : ***سلام این شماره تلفن من است***

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to delete the whole text after 09?

please try like this:

```
$string ="hello this is my phone number 09876543211";

$string = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, "09"));
```

Comment: this is true when language type is english but in my project input language is persian